# text field should be allow only alphanumeric, not only alphabets and numbers?

Tags: regex

I am using following regular expression code but which is allowing alphabets,numbers as well as alphanumeric. But In my case my text field should allow only alphanumeric not only alphabets and only numbers.

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9])$
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Use a lookahead to match the strings which contains at-least a letter and a number.

```
^(?=.*?[A-Za-z])(?=.*?[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9]+$
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` Asserts that we are at the start.
- `(?=.*?[A-Za-z])` Asserts that there must be a letter present in the match.
- `(?=.*?[0-9])` Asserts that there must be a digit present in the match.
- `[A-Za-z0-9]+` Matches one or more letter or digit.
- `$` Asserts that we are at the end.

Comment: You were so fast :) i was trying for that answer . cant upvote reached my daily maximum ;(

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for combination of alphabets and number is acceptable, but not only number, this will work.

```
^(?=.*?[A-Za-z])[A-Za-z0-9]+$
```

`(?=.*?[A-Za-z])` Asserts that there must be a letter present in the match.

`[A-Za-z0-9]+` Matches one or more letter or digit.